# Trouble rendering a React component depending on the location.pathname

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make the navigation bar render based on the current route in my React application. The goal is to render it on all routes except the root `'/'`, and I've tried various ways, as seen in the code and the comments within it. I've also added `location.pathname` as a dependency to the `useEffect`, but that only causes it to return to the initial route `'/'` every time the route changes. I need to render or not render the `NavigationBar` depending on the current route of the application. How can I achieve this?

```
const NavigationBar = () => {
  /*     const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        // Almacenar la ruta en el localStorage cada vez que cambie
        localStorage.setItem('ruta', location.pathname);
 
    }, [location.pathname]);


    const [showNavigate, setShowNavigate] = useState(location.pathname !== '/');
    useEffect(() => {
        const showOnRoutes = ['/lista-de-tareas', '/crear-tarea', '/funciones-adicionales'];
        // Recuperar la ruta del localStorage
        const ruta = localStorage.getItem('ruta');
        setShowNavigate(showOnRoutes.includes(ruta));
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(showNavigate, ' ShowNavigate');
    },[showNavigate]) */

  const location = useLocation();
      
  const rutasParaRenderizar = ['/lista-de-tareas', '/funciones-adicionales', ''];
      
  const debeRenderizar = rutasParaRenderizar.includes(location.pathname);

  return (
    <>
      {/* showNavigate */
        debeRenderizar && (
          <NavigationBarAside>
            <OptionsSection>
              <Search />
              <DivOpciones>
                <NavList>
                  <Link to='/lista-de-tareas'>
                    <NavLi>
                      <DivElementoTexto>
                        Lista de tareas
                      </DivElementoTexto>
                      <SpanElementoIcono>
                        
                      </SpanElementoIcono>
                    </NavLi>
                  </Link>
                  <Link to='/crear-tarea'>
                    <NavLi>
                      <DivElementoTexto>
                        Crear tarea
                      </DivElementoTexto>
                      <SpanElementoIcono>
                        
                      </SpanElementoIcono>
                    </NavLi>
                  </Link>
                  <Link to='/funciones-adicionales'>
                    <NavLi>
                      <DivElementoTexto>
                        Funciones Adicionales
                      </DivElementoTexto>
                      <SpanElementoIcono>
                        
                      </SpanElementoIcono>
                    </NavLi>
                  </Link>
                </NavList>
              </DivOpciones>
              <DivColor>
                <ButtonChangeColor>
                  Cambiar color
                </ButtonChangeColor>
              </DivColor>
            </OptionsSection>
          </NavigationBarAside>
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default NavigationBar
```